# VLC player issue on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: vlc

VLC player isn't working in Ubuntu 14.04. It gives this error:

```
VLC media player 2.1.5 Rincewind (revision 2.1.2+git20140426+r54526+18+11~ubuntu14.04.1)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: The way to solve it is reporting a bug.

Answer (score 3):

Try resetting the configuration as follows:

```
vlc -I qt4 --reset-config --reset-plugins-cache
```

Comment: Worked!! Tried for 2 hours with that thing to work... Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be missing something

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall vlc
```