# Vlc not Run My Xubuntu PC Please help

Tags: xubuntu, vlc

I've just installed VLC on my Xubuntu 14.04 PC, but when I try to run the application it just doesn't start. I've tried a lot of things like re-installing it, but nothing seems to work. If I try to start it with Terminal (I only know the basics) it gives a "segmentation fault (core dumped)".

Comment: Related: [This upvoted answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/461697/37165) mentioned on how to reset configuration in VLC after segmentation fault; It reportedly worked. If solved, you can write own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try and reset the settings:

```
vlc -I qt4 --reset-config --reset-plugins-cache
```

Comment: This tip not work.Terminal showing This..::


ashiq@ashiq-desktop:~/Desktop$ vlc -I qt4 --reset-config --reset-plugins-cache
VLC media player 2.1.6 Rincewind (revision 2.1.6-0-gea01d28)
[0x88e7668] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0x88bb170] main libvlc error: interface "default" initialization failed
ashiq@ashiq-desktop:~/Desktop$